# Matrix field sorting/filtering in the frontend

Tags: matrix, filter, sort

Is there a proper way to do this?  Say I want to have a list of restaurants, and I want to filter them by city AND by type of restaurant.  Is this easily done?  I'm guessing it would have to be AJAX or something.

This would preferably be done using a SELECT field.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Cogweb - we need a lot more information.  How is your Matrix set up? Are the restaurants and cities comnslu?  Or something else? And what template code have you already tried?

Comment: Hi Lisa.  Yes, the categories and cities are select boxes in columns.  The documentation on Matrix doesn't have anything relating to this, unless I'm mistaken on how the search variable works, so I was hoping someone had done this before.

Basically there would be two select boxes, one for each - category and city - and a submit button.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Matrix field settings, Cogweb? I suspect you'll need the search: parameter. :)